# Rails "Missing these required gems" error for installed gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mechanize

I know this has been asked multiple times before, but I've tried those things and still am not having any luck.

For the `mechanize` gem, I keep getting the "Missing these required gems" error when I run `db:migrate` on my production server.

Here's the full error:

```
Missing these required gems:
  mechanize  

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.6.111 at /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  rubygems 1.3.5 at /home/user/.gem/ruby/1.8, /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

Output of `which ruby` is `/usr/bin/ruby`

Output of `which gem` is `/usr/bin/gem`

When I run `gem list` `mechanize (1.0.0)` is definitely in the list.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that you may require i different version of the mechanize gem. Try to work out what version of the gem its looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you may require a different version, Try

```
rake gems:install
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the output of `which rake`?

The output of `which ruby` is `/usr/bin/ruby`, while the rake task reports `/usr/bin/ruby1.8`. Unless one is a symlink to the other, I suspect something is awry in your environment.

Also, looks like you have some gems installed in your user folder. Have you tried installed the gem system-wide with `sudo gem install` or `sudo rake gems:install`?

Comment: You can find out with `gem which mechanize`